# Use transaction in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating new user after that sending notification to user, i don't want to send notifications if user not created whether server side error occurs or on failure of database query. I'm trying to use transaction, but do not have idea where to place transaction code so that if user not created then it should not move to next code block.

```
  $save = new newUser;
    if($save->save()){
    // Notification block
     return response()->json(['status' => true, 'title' => 'Created' , 'message' => 'Data Saved Successfully'],200);
    }
    else
    {
     return response()->json(['status' => false ,'title' => 'Error' , 'message' => 'Data Not Saved'],200);
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use continue & break in your if else Condition.
If they have user exist then continue otherwise break it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is some error while saving the user, e.g. error in database insert query or some other error, then the `$save->save()` will throw an exception. So you can handle it like this:

```
try {
    $save->save();
    return response()->json(['status' => true, 'title' => 'Created' , 'message' => 'Data Saved Successfully'],200);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   report($e);
   return response()->json(['status' => false ,'title' => 'Error' , 'message' => 'Data Not Saved'],200);
}
```

Furthermore, you can try to catch a particular exception and send an appropriate notification for that failure.